# How to define how much to scrollTop?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am loading content via ajax into `#list`, so I am calculating how much it needs to scroll based on the height of `#list` but I need to get 200px less. Once the ajax is finished to load I am running:

```
var pos = jQuery("#list").innerHeight() - 200;
```

Once the height is calculated and I set it in a var I am doing

```
$("body, html").animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000).offset().top;
```

but it is not applying that 200 and it is scrolling to the top without that given 200

Comment: What is the value of `pos`? BTW, if you check for the height of the list before you add it to the DOM it will be 0.

Comment: I am not, I am first loading the content, then I have a callback for the ajax once this is loaded, so the value of pos is defined

Comment: Strange... it works with a fiddle:[link](http://jsfiddle.net/gfusaqmr/3/)

Comment: What is the value of `pos` and why do you have `.offset().top` at the end?

Comment: @JustinY you are right. Didn't need offset. The issue was with my calculation of how much I had to scroll, I wasn't taking into consideration of the header height and the fact I needed to remove the height of the last content row. So it wasn't pos the height but much less, more like / 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need to use `.offset.top()` The issue was with my calculation of how much I had to scroll, I wasn't taking into consideration the header height and the fact I needed to remove the height of the last content row for my case/taste. So it wasn't that `pos` as per my question the height but much less, more like `/ 2` of `#list`

Answer (score 0):

Scroll position is the top of the browser window.  So if you browser window is more then 200px tall it will simply scroll to the bottom.  You need to account for the window height.

if you want a 200px space below the window.

```
var pos = jQuery("#list").innerHeight() - 200 - window.innerHeight;
if(pos < 0) pos = 0;
```